# How to make directory table in Realm

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I have some data with calendar events. I want to save this data in Realm, but only **once** (at apps first launch and when this data updates). Is there any good practice solutions for that (exept using exteral databases)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `RealmConfiguration.Builder#initialData()` you can insert initial data to the database.

Comment: Thank you. Thats what i needed. But not im trying to insert 1 object in the initialData {} block, and 1) My app builds very long time (idk why) 2) Its totally freezes after the launch without any logs. When I remove initialData {}  block? all works fine.

Comment: Its ultra-strange, I havn't seen something like that before, app fust starts with empty screen and there are absolutely clean logcat.